# Dropping duplicate records that exist in a python list with pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I am trying to find and drop the duplicate values that are currently stored in a YAML file.

So far I tried this:
`df_input_file.drop_duplicates(self.duplicate_column_list)`

and `duplicate_column_list  = 'active_proposal_no,active_proposal_revision_no,agency_id,adv_id,network_code,mkt_type,budget_seq_nbr,mkt_year_code'`

The above list I load it from the YAML file.

While trying this I am unable to have the duplicate records identified.

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: If there are, let's say 3 duplicate rows with these set of columns, then which one of the three would you like to have? What is your aggregation logic? Randomly choose any of these three, or else?

Comment: i am not using any logic to select some and reject another but the drop duplicate only.

Comment: If there are 3 records and out of that two are duplicates then 2 (1 genuine and 1 out of 2 duplicates) should go to output file.

Comment: Yeah, so which one of the three is genuine? How would one judge that? So, what's the logic you want to use? Let's say they are `('A','B',2,'UAE'), ('A','B',6,'UK'), ('A','B',0,'USA')` and your `duplicate_column_list` is `['col1','col2']`. Which record to remove?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, your `duplicate_column_list` is actually not a list it is a string of columns comma separated. You need to make this list by using `split` function. `drop_duplicates` treats this whole as a single column, so you are not getting right result.

**Below is the original data: -**

```
duplicate_column_list  = 'active_proposal_no,active_proposal_revision_no,agency_id,adv_id,network_code,mkt_type,budget_seq_nbr,mkt_year_code'
```

**Use Split function to make it list: -**

```
duplicate_column_list  = 'active_proposal_no,active_proposal_revision_no,agency_id,adv_id,network_code,mkt_type,budget_seq_nbr,mkt_year_code'.split(",")
```

**Split will make it list: -**

```
duplicate_column_list  = ['active_proposal_no','active_proposal_revision_no','agency_id','adv_id','network_code','mkt_type','budget_seq_nbr','mkt_year_code']
```

**Now pass this list to drop Duplicates: -**

```
df_input_file.drop_duplicates(duplicate_column_list)
```